# How to use Microsoft Graph Toolkit with Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net, blazor, microsoft-graph-toolkit

There are some tutorials out there for using MGT in various other types of web app, but not for Blazor.

I have previously gotten my Blazor Server app to work correctly using AzureAD authentication and successfully retrieved data via GraphServiceClient. I would like to offer a people-picker UI component, and then discovered that Microsoft Graph Toolkit exists and includes pre-cooked UI component for people-picker and other things.

I added this code to my project based on tutorials:

```
// In _Host.cshtml
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@@microsoft/mgt@@3/dist/bundle/mgt-loader.js"></script>

// In Test.razor
<mgt-msal2-provider
     client-id="[redacted]"
     authority="https://login.microsoftonline.com/[redacted]"
>
<mgt-login></mgt-login>
<mgt-person class="person" person-query="me" view="fourlines" id="online" show-presence></mgt_person>
<mgt-people-picker></mgt-people-picker>
```

The "authority" parameter is needed as I am in a single-tenant application.

The page renders correctly and the mgt-login tag generates a button "Sign In". However:

- nothing appears for the `mgt-person`
- the `mgt-people-picker` shows an input box, but typing anything in it says "We didn't find any matches"
- the "Sign In" button goes to the standard AAD user login UI . I log in with the same user that I logged in initially to the app (as above - using AAD authentication). On first run this gave an AAD error that `redirect-uri` mismatched, so I added this page to the list of redirect-URIs in the application registration. After that, no errors are generated and control returns to the same page after completing the sign-in.

My question is:

- what am I missing here -- why does `mgt-person` show nothing, and the `mgt-people-picker` not reveal anything? No errors appear on the output console or on the page otherwise.
- is this a good way to include UI components for GraphAPI functionality in my app?

I am also unclear on why the `mgt-login` is actually necessary given that the user already logged in when they first enter the app; is it possible for these UI components to pick up the authenticated user that has already occurred via the Blazor authentication code?

Comment: It sounds a lot like Blazor is trying to render this on the server and not giving the rendered webpage everything it needs to correctly operate.

MGT was built as web components as is well tested in SPA scenarios. 

If you have a repo that provides a reproduction of your problems and can raise an issue on the repo https://aka.ms/mgt/issues we'e be happy to spend a little time investigating.

Comment: @GavinB ok; I can't publish details of the AAD tenant I am using but can I make an example without the AAD client IDs etc. and whoever is looking at it will be able to use theirs?

Comment: that would be great!